# How to break index array in loop and use in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have two values(bookingId) in index array and now i want to update query using these values
but right now unable break array in loop, I want to run update query (according to count values in array)
Here is my code,Where i am wrong ?

```
$bookingIds; // contaning two values 176,190
$counts = count($bookingIds);  // counting array values
for ($x = 1; $x <= $counts; $x++) 
    {
        $data = array('approved' => "1");
        $this->db->where('bookingId', $bookingIds);
        $this->db->update('notifications', $data);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should mention an index for your array while looping.And your `$x` must start with `0`

```
$bookingIds; // contaning two values 176,190
$counts = count($bookingIds);  // counting array values
for ($x = 0; $x < $counts; $x++) 
    {
        $data = array('approved' => "1");
        $this->db->where('bookingId', $bookingIds[$x]);
        $this->db->update('notifications', $data);
    }
```

Comment: I thought you were more correct when you suggested using Base 0 for the index and the array.

Comment: @GetSet i thought it too but then i looked at the condition btw can you help me if i'm wrong?

Comment: You're likely right. `$bookingIds` would most probably already be Base 0 since OP relies on `count()` which would be the Base 1 total of that.

Comment: Thanks @GetSet now i have changed the condition so that it is better for OP to understand as well thanks for your reply though 

Comment: No prob. I just hope OP realizes or understands that in going to Base 0, the `<=` would be a logical error.

Answer (score 1):

One refactoring of the above using foreach to remove the whole indexing issue would be

```
$data = array('approved' => "1");
foreach ($bookingsIds as $bookingId )
{
    $this->db->where('bookingId', $bookingId);
    $this->db->update('notifications', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using a framework; if it provides a `whereIn()` method, it would be more efficient to use it (runs less SQL queries):

```
$data = ['approved' => '1'];
$this->db
    ->whereIn('bookingId', $bookingIds)
    ->update('notifications', $data);
```

(Just be aware you can't put thousands and thousands of values in such a "where in" clause, because the query would be huge. Personally I process this kind of stuff in chunks, like 500 records per query.)

(Also, make sure no error happens if the "where in" array (here, `$bookingIds`) is empty. It's a special case, that the framework has to handle properly.)